# how save user from custom form in database

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

Below is my code comprising of django forms.py and views.py file. 
I want save new user. How to achieve this?

forms.py

```
from django import forms


class SignUpForm(forms.Form):
    first_name = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'first'}))
    last_name = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'first'}))
    email = forms.EmailField(widget=forms.EmailInput(attrs={'class': 'first'}))
    password = forms.CharField(widget = forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class':'first'}))
    re_password = forms.CharField(widget = forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class':'first'}))
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import  HttpResponse
import datetime
from . import forms

def regform(request):
    form=forms.SignUpForm()
    if request.method=='POST':
        form=form.SignUpForm(request.POST)
    else:
        html="welcome"
    return render(request,'home/home.html', {'html':html, 'form':form})
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2017/02/18/how-to-create-user-sign-up-view.html)will be resourceful. Also, read Django Official docs on User management